# maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:effective-settings failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing

Tags: java, maven

I'm getting follow issue when run `mvn install`:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:effective-settings (gerar-effective-settings) on project big-dados-deploy-api: Execution gerar-effective-settings of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:effective-settings failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:effective-settings: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.maven.settings.Settings.getRuntimeInfo()Lorg/apache/maven/settings/RuntimeInfo;
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/Users/brunowego/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-help-plugin/2.1.1/maven-help-plugin-2.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/Users/brunowego/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.6/maven-reporting-api-2.0.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/Users/brunowego/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-7.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/Users/brunowego/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.0/commons-cli-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/Users/brunowego/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-api/2.4.3/maven-plugin-tools-api-2.4.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/Users/brunowego/.m2/repository/jtidy/jtidy/4aug2000r7-dev/jtidy-4aug2000r7-dev.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/Users/brunowego/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/Users/brunowego/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-4/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/Users/brunowego/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.7/plexus-utils-1.5.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/Users/brunowego/.m2/repository/jdom/jdom/1.0/jdom-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/Users/brunowego/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.3/xstream-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/Users/brunowego/.m2/repository/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.4c/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/Users/brunowego/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
```

Java Version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_192"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_192-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.192-b12, mixed mode)
```

Apache Maven Version:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T15:29:23-02:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven@3.2/3.2.5_1/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_192, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Users/brunowego/.jabba/jdk/adopt@1.8.0-192/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_BR, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Comment: I recommend to use a more recent versions of maven-help-plugin:2.1.1 cause version 2.1.1 is 10 years old. I strongly recommend to upgrade to most recent version and you should use maven version 3.6.3 and not going down to 3.0.X ...Furthermore why is maven-help-plugin bound to life cycle in your pom file?

Comment: This is a legacy project where I can not change.

Comment: In particular if it's a legacy project you should upgrade your build system step by step...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After downgrade from Apache Maven version `3.6.3` to `3.0.4`, everything works.

To do this, I used [Maven Version Manager](https://mvnvm.org/).

```
echo 'mvn_version=3.0.4' > mvnvm.properties

nvm install
```

Comment: On this project, I can not do much, is a legacy project.